# Time-driven trigger not executing any SpreadsheetApp.getUi functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Why would Time-Driven triggers not call any ‍‍‍‍`SpreadsheetApp.getUi` or `Browser.xxx()`, functions?

If I manually play the function, the lines are executed, but with a time based trigger, the function is called, all other lines are executed, except any calls to the above.

I wanted a time-driven trigger to display an alert on a spreadsheet based on the time freq set.

Here is a simple code,
Time-driven trigger set to run every minute as an example. Tried it with various other time settings.

```
function InputTime()
{

Logger.log("This code ran");     // This works fine.

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Warning 1");        // Does not work

this.SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("warning 2");   // Does not work

Browser.msgBox("warning 3");                     // Does not work
}
```

Any idea? Also, modifying the values in the sheet by first getting the Id of the sheet and the sheet name ( as suggested by Sergi here), allows the sheet to be edited fine. Similarly is there any way to tie Alert notifications to the particular spreadsheet?

Answer (score 5):

Time-Driven triggers functions are unable to interact with Ui, they run in their own scope , independently of your session.

This is the intended behavior, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Just reiterating.. a time-driven script runs at a given time, what if you're not logged in? Or what if there's multiple users? Apps Script has no support for this kind of usage (showing a popup to whoever is online, if there's anyone). To connect with a user's session and show him dialogs, your script has to be triggered in a "session-related" fashion. That would be: a menu, button, edit or open events. Or straight from the script editor, like you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Serge, and Henrique.